How to determine the attorney, if any, in a published patent application?
I am currently reading a published patent application.
I cannot find the attorney name.
Is there a way that I can conclude that the patent was drafted without an attorney?


Is there a way that I can conclude that the patent was drafted without an attorney?

In terms of XY-problem, this shouldn't really matter for anything. The only time one would care about this field is if the application is so well drafted that one would like to hire the same attorney.
In general, one can not know (unless the applicant truthfully states it for some reason). "Pro se" applicants are free to consult with attorneys (and agents) and have them draft entire applications if desired without making them of record.
Even on patents that have attorneys listed, I don't think that database field is even intended to represent authorship of the document. At a large law firm, one can expect that the listed attorneys just give the final sign off on whatever the unnamed lower echelon lawyers are churning out.

There used to be a place on published applications that listed the attorney/agent of record, like there is on granted patents. That was stopped sometime about 2015 + or - a couple of years.
You can find that information by looking up the application at the PatentCenter site. There is a tab for attorney of record. You can also look at individual submissions for the signature of the representative.
